# when i try to update then i get something as given below.what is it? i always get the message "/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on' "

Tags: updates, 17.10

```
$ sudo apt-get update
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
0% [Working]/etc/host.conf: line 3: bad command `nospoof on'
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu artful InRelease

  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/download.sublimetext.com_apt_stable_InRelease into data 
Fetched 229 kB in 3s (76.4 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:5
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:22 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:22
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/download.sublimetext.com_apt_stable_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:31
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:32 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:32
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Fortunately there aren't any close votes remaining on this question anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be very clear.

In `/etc/host.conf` line 3 you have a line with illegal content. You have propably edited the file at some point in time. Revert the edit, eventually by marking the line as a comment by inserting a `#` as first characther in line 3.

After installation of 17.10 it has the following contents in `/etc/host.conf`:

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

You can revert your config to this one.

Then you have  lot of lines defined both in `/etc/apt/sources.list`and in files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`. Delete the lines in one of the files .. and only in one of them. Or figure out wht the correct syntax should be.

`/etc/apt/sources.list`and the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` configures what repositories Ubuntu installs and updates packages from.

Comment: I edited this answer and added contents of clean fresh /etc/host.conf for 17.10.